# If we connect the two terminals of a semiconductor diode with a simple wire, then will the current flow?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, semiconductor-physics

We know that inside a semiconductor diode, there is an internal electric field from the N side to the P side. This implies that the N side is at a higher potential than the P side of a semiconductor diode. Thus, if we connect the two terminals of a diode with a simple wire then the current should flow, but my textbook (Concepts of Physics - H C Verma) says that the current will not flow. The reason is not explained in the book. Could somebody explain to me, why the current will not flow when it seems it should?

Following diagram shows the internal electric field and corresponding potential barrier.

[image]